# Change value in textbox from combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, textbox

I'm trying to make the textbox value change based on the value of the combobox. It's should be fairly straight forward, but I'm struggling with this.

```
Private Sub Combobox1_Change()
 x = Combobox1.Value
 textbox1.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B") & x
End Sub
```

P.S. For clarity, I've never been a professional programmer or code writer.

Comment: If `x` is a number then `Textbox1.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & x).Value`

Comment: Note: You will have to ensure that the combobox1 change event returns a valid number else you will get an error. You need to handle that.

Comment: The ComboBox's `Value` is whatever is in the row of the `BoundColumn` indicated by the `ListIndex` property which isn't necessarily what you see on the screen. If you entered something in the ComboBox that isn't in its list there will be a difference. Try the `Text` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the bracket in the wrong place.

```
Range("B" & x).value
```

I also would prefer this version:

```
Range("B1").Offset(x - 1).Value
```